# When to perform initial scrolling of custom View

Tags: android

i have a custom view in which id like to do some scrollY when it finishes inflating. the problem is that it seems that at that point (`onFinishInflate()`) the calculations about different x and y position of the view itself and its children aren't ready yet to give me the correct values, e.g. it gives me 0 when thats clearly wrong. 
When is the first point at which i can get correct calculations?

Comment: How about `onSizeChanged`?